# AsynkTask. Как завершить преждевременно. Break?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    answer = "Вернулся " + params[0];
    do {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.gc();
        try {
            WeakCallback.get().getResult(answer);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"активити пересоздан");
            break;
        }
    } while (x > 1);

    return null;
}
```

Экспериментирую. Запустил Активити, а через него перехожу на второе активити, в нем запускаю `AsyncTask` . Он крутится в бесконечном цикле. Ссылку на активити держит в `WeakReference`.Выхожу из активити, на первое активити. `AsyncTask` продолжает работу, пока я не начну грузить картинку и этим самым пробуждаю `GC`. Мое активити удаляется из памяти, я ловлю исключение и если его не обработать выходом из `AsyncTask` , то `AsynckTask` никогда не умрет (ну пока приоритет `GC` не доедет до него, а до этого момента будет жрать заряд и память).  А вопрос собственно в том, правильно ли использовать оператор `break` . `Return`  не могу применить, так как к убитой активити обратится. Завершит ли `break`  работу `AsyncTask` ?  Из цикла он выходит однозначно.

Comment: Вроде должен выйти из цикла и попасть на return , наверно так и происходит, но странно , что приложение не падает, ведь null вернуть уже некуда

Comment: Объект, возвращаемый методом `doInBackground` передается в метод `OnPostExecute`. При корректной реализации второго метода падать ничего не должно. И замечание: в `doInBackground` не нужно обращаться к коллбэкам, отдавать данные для `UI` нужно в методе `OnPostExecute`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AsyncTask может быть отменен в любое время при вызове cancel (boolean). После isCancelled (), будет возвращать true. Дальше вызовется onCancelled (Object), вместо onPostExecute (Object). Для гарантии отмены задачи как можно быстрее, вы должны проверять возвращаемое значение isCancelled () в doInBackground (Object []), например, внутри цикла как у вас в примере.

Comment: Я немного запутался. Я передаю в блоке catch в cancel значение true. Оператор break убрал. Как я понимаю, это значит  что поток должен прерваться и должны выпасть исключения типо InterruptedException. Но этого не происходит, не дождался я завершения цикла.  Это тот случай, при котором cancel(true) не смог завершить задачу сам?  Если да, то назревает другой вопрос. А чем плох способ такой: в cancel передаем true и проверяем isCancelled ?   Зачем передавать false и проверять  isCancelled? ведь с true шансы еще выше.